# Not able to perform COUNT and GROUP BY operations on field elasticsearch SQL

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, kibana

I am using **Elasticsearch SQL** to fetch data from the **elasticsearch** index in **canvas[Kibana]** for visualization.

Here is my **ESSQL** query:

`SELECT COUNT(status), status FROM "indexName" GROUP BY status`

Note: *field **status** is of type **text***

When I try to execute this query the below error occurred:

```
[essql] > Unexpected error from Elasticsearch:
[verification_exception] Found 1 problem(s) line 1:57: Field [status]
of data type [text] cannot be used for grouping;
No keyword/multi-field defined exact matches for [status]; define one
or use MATCH/QUERY instead
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are not allowed to count or perform aggregations on a text field. The same is mentioned in the error description you have got 
"[verification_exception] Found 1 problem(s) line 1:57: Field [status]
of data type [text] cannot be used for grouping;"

AFAIK elastic search tokenises the content of a text field into an inverted index. And so a text like "a room full of brooms" would be indexed into as "a","room","full","of","brooms".

This would depend on the type of analyzer being used also.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html